# Bitmap is null when convert imageview in bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I need put effect blur in image, but when convert imageview into bitmap it is showing an error (NullPointerException).

See the code:

```
// mImages is a list of string (links http of images in web)      
Picasso.with(mContext).load(mImages.get(position)).fit().centerInside().into(imageView);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of Picasso callback:

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(mImages.get(position))
    .fit()
    .centerInside()
    .into(imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override 
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Drawable is ready
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        }

        @Override 
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```

Make sure your ImageView's `width` and `height` are NOT defined by *`WRAP_CONTENT`*.

This is because `fit()` requires the size of the ImageView when it is measured.

If your `ImageView` has its width and height defined by *`WRAP_CONTENT`*, its methods `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` will return 0 and you will not see the image.

Comment: Has generated this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fit cannot be used with a Target. in first line

Comment: Sorry about that. I have submitted a new answer that is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure  imageView != null ? wrap it inside if condition

```
if(imageView != null){
// write your code here
}else{
//log something like the following
Log.e("imageView","NULL");
}
```

Are you sure it's built? Try next code

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: I entered the verification as you suggested. The imageview is not null.

I put the suggested code and it is still giving null in the bitmap

Comment: Actually I managed to solve with the solution passed by @User123, but thanks for the help